# iBeacon implemenation - Use cases

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ibeacon

I'm trying to figure use case to deploy beacon to detect duration customer stay at specific sections in a mall.

As i understand I can use one unique UUID declare as region to be monitor by the app, but the didEnterRegion does not providing the major & minor needed to identify which beacon was detected. The app will be able to have a short time to do the ranging to retrieve the major & minor for about 10s after the didEnterRegion trigger.

What if I have beacons that have overlaps coverage detection space?
Let's say the space have 4 beacons and when customer move from 1 beacon to another there won't be any exit/enter region trigger as the UUID/region are still the same.
What will be the better implementation or solution for scenario that I want to log time duration of customer stay at different beacons?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A few tips:

- Use a single ProximityUUID.  Use a different major value per zone in the mall.  Make the minor value be different for each beacon.
- Set up a CLBeaconRegion for each zone (major) and start both monitoring and ranging for each.  (Up to 20 max).
- [Extend background ranging](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2014/11/13/extending-background-ranging-on-ios.html) for 3 min per region entry/exit.
- When ranging, use the estimated distance to decide which beacon is closest.  Whatever zone that is in (major value) is the Mall zone. If it is not the same as the current zone, mark a timestamp for exiting that zone and a timestamp for entering the new one.
- If you get a monitoring region exit event for the zone the phone is currently in, mark a timestamp for exiting that zone.

Comment: As I understand if the beacons have overlaps coverage and they share the same UUID. EnterRegion will only trigger once when the device first enter the region but won't trigger when get into second or third beacon range. ExitRegion will only trigger when device totally leave all the beacons with the same UUID. So the 3 min extend for ranging is not enough for monitoring the device movement if the device stay in the region for long time.

Comment: For entry/exit, it is not just the UUID but the full region definition that matters, including the major.  Anytime the user starts or stops seeing beacons matching any region definition, you get a new monitoring callback and the 3 minute clock starts again.

Comment: Any reason not use different UUID instead of major to set up CLBeaconRegion?

Comment: You can use different UUIDs, but the standard practice is to use fewer when possible.  This makes troubleshooting easier using scanning apps with which UUIDs have to be pre-configured.